# Why isn't my Google OAuth configuration not working?

Tags: meteor, google-api, google-oauth, meteor-accounts, ngrok

Ever since Google made some minor changes to their **Google OAuth API** side, I haven't been able to correctly configure and use the **Google OAuth**, indicated by the error message: **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch** The configurations fail, despite me following the setting up Google OAuth instructions in detail.

Can someone kindly help point out what I am doing wrong or missing?

Just in case you aren't familiar with what I mean by the **Google OAuth instructions**, find below an image illustrating what I mean:

[image]

I skip **2. "Create Project"**  (since the project already has a priorly recorded name)
and head on to step **3.**

[image: an indicating what my OAuth Consent screen looks like]

After entering an **email address** and the **product name** as suggested 
 in step **.3** , I save.

I carry out steps **4**, **5** without any problem.

On step **6** I realise that my **configuration instructions** isn't up to date, because as at this point, I notice that Google has added a few **Mandatory** fields to be filled in. A person now has to **Authorize Javascript Origins** as shown in the image below. Note the https://3e908b9b.ngrok.io (fictitious for this case) link that I filled in.

[image]

I click the **Authorized domains list** link that takes me back to the **OAuth Consent Screen** and paste in the exact same link https://3e908b9b.ngrok.io as seen in the image below, then save as seen in the image below.

[image]

Doing this, permits me to complete the process successfully as seen in the image below finalised by clicking **Save**.

[image]

On my Meteor app side, I finalise by filling in the **Client ID** and the **Client Secret** details, as seen in the image below.

[image]

When i later try to login using **Google OAuth** I get this frustrating error message Seen below..[image]

This is an issue i never used to get untill Google made a few changes on their side. I cant seem to figure this out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is the redirect uri you are sending from `https://3XXXXXngrok.io/_oauth/google` does not match one of the ones you have supplied in the Google Developer console for your project.

You appear to have set `https://3XXXXXX.io/_oauth/google?close` they must exactly match.

**Solution**

simply add https://3XXXXXngrok.io/_oauth/google as a redirect uri or remove ?close from the one you have added